# Two problems with my pi (cron, and bootup w/o HDMI)

Tags: boot, hdmi, cron

I have two problems with my pi right now.

1) The device won't boot unless I have a HDMI cable plugged in.. I am using it headless, and I'm trying to reduce cable clutter, so needing a HDMI cable to boot the machine is not ideal. It works if I let the pi boot and then plug out the cable.

2) I have problem getting cron to work. I typed crontab -e and added these lines:

```
*/10 *   * * *   /ks/monitor.sh
@reboot          /ks/monitor.sh
```

However monitor.sh doesn't seem to run, either at boot or every 10 minutes. I also tried adding it to sudo crontab -e, and edited permissions of monitor.sh to 777. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: 1) What options are enabled in `/boot/config.txt`?
2) Are you very sure that monitor.sh produces output? IE: If you run the script normally, is it fine?

Comment: Don't forget that cron runs /bin/sh (not bash) with a very limited environment. Your script is probably assuming a more complete PATH definition, so try explicitly adding paths to commands in the script outside /bin, /usr/bin, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This should be 2 questions. I will answer your question about your Raspberry Pi not booting unless the HDMI cable is plugged in.

This seems to be a [bug in the firmware](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/75). Although it does seem to be fixed in a newer firmware update. Have you tried running `rpi-update`? Or if you dont have rpi-update, try the following terminal command. Just a note `rpi-update` will make your RPi more up to date than the following command.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I am also running my Pi in headless mode w/o HDMI cables plugged in, and it works fine. I am running the 2013-02-09 version of Raspbian Wheezy, plus I have cron-apt running, which automatically upgrades packages.

Answer (score 1):

First of all; avoid chmod 0777, just use 0711 if you just want to run as root.

Change the crontab entries like this;

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /ks/monitor.sh
@reboot      /bin/sh /ks/monitor.sh
```